# Random forest shows higher feature importance over features that are not so relevant

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

Now I am trying to use local features to predict local targets using random forest regressor. For example, the total data contains information about 3 areas but I only want to predict the target value of area 1. So I only used features of area 1 as well as all the features to do the training.

Using only local features gives higher test accuracy than using the global information (0.97 vs. 0.86). Does it say that features other than of area 1 are redundant? But the feature importance of the global model shows, on average, the importance of features in area 2 is higher.

I was expecting the consistency between the two, that is, the global model shows higher feature importance in area 1 with respect to the target in area 1. But the result tells another story.

How can I interpret this? Or how else can I prove that the local features are more important to local targets because the accuracy seems to say so?

I am not super familiar with random forest algorithm. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: It could be best to go back to the start with this - try a few tutorials so you're sure you understand all the basics. Sorry, I'm not sure where exactly to start other than by suggesting this. That is not my downvote btw! Always ask questions - perhaps you can ask more specific questions about the code or results after looking back over some of the docs or a tutorial though. Best of luck!

Comment: @MJM Thanks for the reply! I just read about that the default random forest in scikit-learn has bias when it comes to feature selection, especially in high dimensional data. The permutation importance seems to be more reliable. I would try that and also  learn the mechanism of RF in details. Thanks again

Comment: That's great you've found some reasons! Well done, keep up the work - another win for the good guys!